# Pandas routine to modify Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to python and pandas and I'm trying to automate the conversion of a csv (automatically produced by the webinar platform) that looks more or less like this:

```
import pandas as pd
course={
    "Name":["John","John","John","Nathan","Nathan","Nathan"],
    "Last":["Smith","Smith","Smith","Rogers","Rogers","Rogers"],
    "Date":["01/01/2021","03/01/2021","05/01/2021","01/01/2021","03/01/2021","05/01/2021"],
    "Time_connected":["01:55","02:05","01:35","01:55","02:00","02:01"]
}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=course)
```

Into something similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
course={
    "Name":["John","Nathan"],
    "Last":["Smith","Rogers"],
    "01/01/2021":["01:55","01:55"],
    "03/01/2021":["02:05","02:00"],
    "05/01/2021":["01:35","02:01"]
}
cc=pd.DataFrame(data=course)
```

I tried with a lot of for loops, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
course={
    "Name":["John","John","John","Nathan","Nathan","Nathan"],
    "Last":["Smith","Smith","Smith","Rogers","Rogers","Rogers"],
    "Date":["01/01/2021","03/01/2021","05/01/2021","01/01/2021","03/01/2021","05/01/2021"],
    "Time_connected":["01:55","02:05","01:35","01:55","02:00","02:01"]
}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=course)

usr=list(df["Last"].value_counts().index)
dd=list(df["Date"].value_counts().index)
dd.insert(0, "Last")

df_fin=pd.DataFrame(columns=dd)
df_fin.set_index("Last")

for u in usr:
    
    df_fin=df_fin.append({"Last":u}, ignore_index=True)
    df_fin.loc[df[u],df["Date"]]==df[u],df["Time_connected"]
```

but it doesn't work and I can't find a way to obtain that result, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can a person have multiple `Time_connected` for the same day?

Comment: No, during the training days there are just a couple of hour of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
In [210]: df.pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Last'], columns=['Date'], values=['Time_connected'], aggfunc='first').droplevel
     ...: (0, 1).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
Out[210]:
     Name    Last 01/01/2021 03/01/2021 05/01/2021
0    John   Smith      01:55      02:05      01:35
1  Nathan  Rogers      01:55      02:00      02:01
```

A standard pivot table with `first` as the aggfunc (or max/min work as well as long as there's just one Time_connected)